# Set custom id to list element walker custom function

Tags: navigation, walker, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a navigation with bootstrap in a custom WP theme.
I have managed to get this result:

```
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27">...</li>
```

However I have already styled my navigation before transforming it to WP navigation like this:

```
<li class="" id="nava"><a href="--><?php //echo get_option('home');?><!--/">Home</a></li>
```

I want to replace id="menu-item-27" with id="nava".

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You could try the `nav_menu_item_id` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `nav_menu_item_id` filter like this:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', function( $menu_id, $item, $args, $depth )
{
    if( 'menu-item-27' === $menu_id )
        $menu_id = 'nava';

    return $menu_id;
}, 10, 4 );
```

but I this is "unstable" regarding the menu ID, if you delete and re-insert menu items. You might also want to target a specific menu location.

A common method, that I like for it's flexibility, is to check for a specific CSS classes, that we can set within the navigational UI in the backend.

Here's an example where we check for the `set-id-nava` class. If it is set, then we override the CSS id with `nava`:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', function( $menu_id, $item, $args, $depth )
{
    if( in_array( 'set-id-nava', (array) $item->classes ) )
        $menu_id = 'nava';

    return $menu_id;
}, 10, 4 );
```

We could also make this more dynamically and check for `set-id-???`.

We could even add an extra input field to set CSS id's for each menu item. But that would require more work.

If you don't want the `set-id-nava` as a CSS class, then you could remove it, e.g. via the `nav_menu_css_class` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @birgire I edited the walker class like this:

```
From: 
$id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
To:
$id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'nava', $item, $args );
```

Comment: Please don't edit core files, this will be deleted when you updated. Let me construct an example instead.